# (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code

Tags: java, scala

i m working on ubuntu:15.10

- export JAVA6_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-ppc64el
- git clonehttps://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala.git && \
  cd jackson-module-scala && \ sbt 'set resolvers += "Sonatype OSS
  Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"' test

I get the following stack trace

- root@a5d741c5478f:/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala# sbt 'set resolvers
  += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"' test
- [info] Loading project definition from /FasterXML/jackson-module
  scala/project
- [info] Updating
  {file:/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/project/}jackson-module-scala-build...
- [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
- [info] Done updating.
- [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to

  /FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
- [info] Set current project to jackson-module-scala (in build
  file:/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/)
- [info] Defining *:resolvers
- [info] The new value will be used by *:externalResolvers
- [info] Reapplying settings...
- [info] Set current project to jackson-module-scala (in build
  file:/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/)
- [info] Updating
  {file:/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/}jackson-module-scala...
- [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
- [info] Done updating.
- [info] Compiling 52 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to
  /FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/target/scala-2.11/classes...
- [warn]
  /FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/modifiers/GenTypeModifier.scala:12:

  method construct in object SimpleType is deprecated: see
  corresponding Javadoc for more information.
- [warn]   protected def UNKNOWN =
  SimpleType.construct(classOf[AnyRef]) [warn]
                      ^ [warn] /FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/ser/OptionSerializerModule.scala:150:
  method getPropertyType in class BeanPropertyWriter is deprecated: see
  corresponding Javadoc for more information.
- [warn]
  classOf[Option[_]].isAssignableFrom(writer.getPropertyType) [warn]
  ^ [warn] two warnings found [error] (compile:compileIncremental)
  javac returned nonzero exit code [error] Total time: 205 s, completed
  Mar 17, 2016 9:23:23 AM

can someone help me with what is it that i need to fix in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the modules requires a Java 6 VM, but you're using Java 7 (`java-7-openjdk-ppc64el`). Have you tried downgrading?

If that doesn't help, please update your question (better formating, it's cumbersome to read it this way) and include anything else that might help, because there is no error message in the output you provided.